# Is it necessary to set instance variable in resource controller `#create` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having resource `Foobar` with the following controller:

```
class FoobarController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foobar = Foobar.new(baz: params[:baz])
    @foobar.build_data
  end

  def create
    @foobar = Foobar.new(foobar_params)
    respond_with(@foobar)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Is it necessary to set instance variable `@foobar` in `#create` method? Could not I just write

```
def create
  Foobar.new(foobar_params).tap &method(:respond_with)
end
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what content types you respond with. The [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) describe exactly what happens when you call `respond_with`. In your case, in the `create` action, `respond_with` is the same as the following, assuming you did not specify any other format than html in a `respond_to` call in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @foobar.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Foobar was successfully created.'
    format.html { redirect_to(@foobar) }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
```

The only case where the `@foobar` instance variable would be necessary is, if there is a validation error and your `new.html` template includes `@foobar`. If the `foobar_params` are always valid, then `respond_with` will always respond with a redirect to the `show` action, so the instance variable is unnecessary.